# How to get Index in Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need some help here, for example I have the following item in my datatable

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RowX | 1 | 12 | 0 |  |  |
| RowX | 2 | 12 | 0 |  |  |
| RowX | 3 | 12 | 0 |  |  |
| RowY | 3 | 12 | 1 |  |  |
| RowY | 1 | 12 | 1 |  |  |

and I want to get the index of this row

RowX  |   3  |  12  |   0   |         |

because I want to update the Column 5 and Column 6 of this row. If I used the above query like

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
let r = row.Field<string>("Column1")
let s = row.Field<int>("Column2")
let t = row.Field<string>("Column3")
let u = row.Field<string>("Column4")
where r == DataRowX && s == 12 && t == 3 && u == 0
select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);

DataTable1.Rows[index]["Column5"] = intUpdateValueColumnx;
DataTable1.Rows[index]["Column6"] = intUpdateValueColumny;
DataTable1.AcceptChanges();
```

This is not working because Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' to 'int'. How to get the index?

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumerable.Where` returns multiple elements, in this case `IEnumerable<int>`, you can use a `foreach` to enumerate all:

```
foreach(int index in indices) // renamed index to indices
{
    DataTable1.Rows[index]["Column5"] = intUpdateValueColumnx;
    DataTable1.Rows[index]["Column6"] = intUpdateValueColumny;
}
DataTable1.AcceptChanges();
```

If you're sure that it only contains one you can use `First` or `Single`(throws exception on multiple).

```
int firstIndex = indices.First();
DataTable1.Rows[firstIndex]["Column5"] = intUpdateValueColumnx;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` should be an `int` that represents the position or "index" of the row you want to change.

You are setting `index` to an `EnumerableRowCollection` with your first line,

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
let r = row.Field<string>("Column1")
let s = row.Field<int>("Column2")
let t = row.Field<string>("Column3")
let u = row.Field<string>("Column4")
where r == DataRowX && s == 12 && t == 3 && u == 0
select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

so `index` is actually a a set of indices.

---

You probably want to do something like,

```
foreach (var row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
        r.Field<string>("Column1") == DataRowX &&
        r.Field<int>("Column2") == 12 &&
        r.Field<string>("Column3") == "3" &&
        r.Field<string>("Column4") == "0"))
{
    row.SetField("Column5", intUpdateValueColumnx);
    row.SetField("Column6", intUpdateValueColumny);
}

DataTable1.AcceptChanges();
```

This will update all the rows that match your criteria. There could be many or none.